# Bus Error 10 in C Programming resulting from array of integers

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to create an array that acts as a queue. I know that there are other ways to do this such as a node but for my purposes, I am using an array of size 10.

I am running into an error "bus 10 error" Based on what I have read it seems like it is a memory allocation issue or that I am trying to override a value I cannot.

In my code, I have the array initialized with all values equal to -1.

the section of code that is causing the issue seems to be

```
void add_int(int num, int size) {
    int i = size;
    while (i <= size) {
        if (i == 0) {
            active_frames[i] = num;
        }
        active_frames[i] = active_frames[i - 1];
        i--;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this code is causing a bus10 error. I am not too familiar with C programming so please let me know what I can clarify to get better help. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. Where is this array declared? How is it defined? How is it initialized? And remember to show us code that actually builds, and doesn't have syntax errors (like a *type* where an expression is expected).

Comment: What do you think makes your loop terminate?

Comment: As a probable hint, are you really *sure* about that loop condition? When will it terminate?

Comment: A couple of hints. First, if you want to traverse an array, use a `for` loop. Second, the last valid index in an array of size `size` is `size-1`. In other words, all valid indices are *less* than the size. Not less or equal to.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: And more to the point, all valid indices are *nonnegative*.  Which will not be the case for `i` after *decrementing* it a bunch of times.

Comment: This would be an excellent opportunity to use a debugger (and to learn how to use one if you don't already).  If you would single-step this code, paying attention to the value of `i` as you go, you would see the problem immediately, and save a bunch of time for yourself (and us).   People have spent zillions of hours creating development tools for C: use them!

Comment: `active_frames[i] = int;` is strange because `int` is a _type_ and _not_ a value.

Comment: if `i == 0`, then `active_frames[i - 1]` isn't going to go well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 major problems in your code:

- the first iteration accesses `active_frames[i]` with `i = size`: this has invalid behavior if `active_frames` is an array of length `size`.
- the loop never stops because `i <= size` is always true if you decrement `i` starting from `i = size`. the code will write to `active_frames[-1]` etc. which is another access outside the bounds of the array, hence invalid behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
void add_int(int num, int size) {
    int i = size;
    while (i-- > 1) {
        active_frames[i] = active_frames[i - 1];
    }
    active_frames[0] = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where `i` is equal to 0 you set `active_frames[0]` to `num`. and then you try to set `active_frames[0]` to `active_frames[-1]`. except that `active_frames[-1]` doesn't exist which causes the BUS_ERROR. To fix this, you need to add an else like this:

```
void add_int(int num, int size){

    int i = size;
    while (i <= size){
        if(i == 0)
            active_frames[i] = num;
        else
            active_frames[i] = active_frames[i-1];
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

```
// Accessing an element out of bounds (index 5)
int value = arr[5];

printf("Value: %d\n", value);

return 0;
```

}